# why does name get replaced by only the first name in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-writing

```
with open("./Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as f:
    names = f.readlines()

with open("./Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt", mode="r+") as f:
    letter = f.read()
    for name in names:
        letter = letter.replace("[name]", name)
        f.write(letter)
```

I am trying to replace the string [name] with actual names stored in a list. The problem is that in all iterations only the first name is replacing the [name] string.

Comment: After you've replaced `[name]` with an actual name, then the string obviously no longer contains `[name]`!  You need two different variables here - one that keeps the original string read from the file, and one that is the result of replacement.

Comment: You can use the parameter ```count``` to limit the number of replacements.

Comment: Can you provide a explanation or example of the format of the text files.

Comment: For reference, here is [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, it would be more helpful if you provided the contents of the files.

I think your issue is that when you initilise letter it is stored as a string and when you use the `.replace()` method all of the instances are being replaced on the first iteration of the loop. On the next iteration, all of the instances are already replaced so the `.replace()` method will do nothing.

The `.replace()` function has an overload where you can specify the maximum amount of occurrences to replace so instead of `letter = letter.replace("[name]", name)` you should use `letter = letter.replace("[name]", name, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from strings import Template

with open("./Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as f:
    names = f.readlines()

with open("./Input/Letters/template_starting_letter.txt") as f:
    letter_tmpl = f.read()

tmpl = Template(letter_tmpl)

with open("./Input/Letters/starting_letter.txt", "w+") as f_out:
    for name in names:
        letter = tmpl.safe_substitute(name=name)
        f.write(letter)
```

It's not the best idea to use `letter` several times for different tasks. In your case you replace something in `letter` and assign it to `letter`. The next thing is that string.replace('pattern', value) is done over all occurances, not only the first one. Means that once replaces `[name]` won't exist anymore.

A much better idea would be creating a template with the variable `${name}` somewhere and use `Template` from the `strings` library. In this case you can loop over all names, take the template, substitute the variable and append the final text to some output file.

Not tested, but should work.